# Caching Frameworks for .NET other than Velocity

Tags: .net, caching

What other caching frameworks are available for .NET besides the project codenamed Velocity. What are the ALT.NET options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always [Oracle Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/coherence/index.html).  Many of the caching technologies mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383920/what-is-the-best-library-for-java-to-gridcluster-enable-your-application#383929) also have .Net libraries (eg [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/).

Answer (score 1):

Distributed cache frameworks?  Free ones?

There's a Windows version of memcached but it's not great.  There's [Cacheman](http://www.sriramkrishnan.com/blog/2008/02/cacheman-fast-distributed-hashtable-for.html), which seems ok.  I'd recommend Velocity over those, I've seen Velocity used on a pretty high traffic website and it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Ncache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html) and the free [NCache Express](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/ncache_express.html).  Also take a look at [ScaleOut State Server](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/products/stateServer/index.html).