# memcached Monitoring

Tags: java, memcached

What is the best way to monitor `memcached` from a Java application on a Linux machine?  I would like information such as:

1) Memory used by each object
2) Number of items evicted for reclaiming memory
3) etc..

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old:

But for some quick monitoring of a running memcached system: ( in ubuntu )

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmemcached-tools
```

This includes a handful of handy tools. The one in particular that I use is **memcstat**

```
$ watch -n1 -d 'memcstat --servers localhost'
```

This will show alot of handy information like for instance:

```
curr_connections: 5
total_connections: 26
get_hits: 202
get_misses: 12
bytes_read: 1650
bytes_written: 74345
```

This is handy because it does not require you to write a single line of code, and better yet will tell you if your caching infrastructure is working like you expect it too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some [information on memcached monitoring](http://www.netuality.ro/monitoring-memcached-with-cacti/tools/20060802) and [another list](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/HowToMonitor).

Memcached from Java is a bit of an odd choice though. I'm curious why you chose it. Caching solutions on Java tend to revolve around, say, [EHCache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/) or [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/). Here is a [more complete list of Java caching solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383920/what-is-the-best-library-for-java-to-grid-cluster-enable-your-application/383929#383929).

Comment: Is there anything about the Java client that makes you say it's an "odd choice" other than it not being a common choice? Also, from the question, it's not clear if the application(s) using memcached are Java-based, or if he just wants the monitoring to be

Comment: Also also, using memcached as a caching solution would enable other clients on other platforms to interact with the cached data too, wouldn't it? Unlike ehcache?

Comment: I mean "odd" as in unusual not necessarily bad. Memcached is primarily associated with PHP. Java-specific solutions will be able to use Java serialization methods (inbuilt and customized) and generally just fit better. Of course there mgiht be another reason like also using PHP, .Net, etc.

Comment: Both links are now dead, unfortunately