# Persistent hash-map, concurrent JDBM

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, persistence

I tested [JDBM2](http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/) which is really a great API to persist data directly in a tree- or hash-map. On the project site it is written that it does not support concurrent access. So my question is: Are there similar open source APIs for Java available which support concurrent read and write operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a basic feature the questions implies is inter-jvm communication? If that is the case, I have successfully used [hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/).

See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383920/what-is-the-best-library-for-java-to-grid-cluster-enable-your-application) that although different has valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a way of wrapping an existent hash map and returning a synchronized map; however you will have to write the synchronization yourself: [Collections#synchronizedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)

It is quite easy to extend an `HashMap` or implement the `Map` interface to enforce some synchronization on `get()` and `put()`, however iterators are more tricky.

There's also a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) but it has some limitations, depending on what you want to do.

The simple approach is to use `Collections#synchronizedMap` and add the synchronization code yourself.

Comment: synchronization does not support concurrent access, it serializes access.

Comment: I think that is what the op wanted.