# Replicate Dynamic loaded groovy classes in cluster nodes

Tags: caching, groovy, jvm, classloader, replication

I'm working on web application where I have some groovy templating engine and some classes [loaded dynamically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21752809/2106516). Those templates are cached in local using `jbosscache`.
When trying to set a clustered environement, I'm going through problem when trying to replicate those templates when running my app in **node1** and I have a `ClassNotFoundException class UITestTemplate` throw in the console in the unmarshalling process which clearlly mean that my application is not able to deserialize an Object with type `UITestTemplate`.
With `jvisualVM` I can see that there is no class `UITestTemplate` in **node2** which makes some sence. But, what seems weird is when do I stop both nodes, then start **node1** an run my web app so those classes get compiled (I can see them in the monitoring tool). Secondly I start **node2** and run my app from there I got the same reported error **which means node1 is unable to deserialize the received object having as a class UITestTemplate while it is loaded into JVM**.

- So does this problem an expected behavior with groovy dynamic generated classes? How to woraround it then?
- Is it related to domain permissions and class loading hierarchy?

**NB:** I only run into problem when trying to replicate cache of those templates as other beans are seamelessly replicated.

It is really a blocking issue and I really rely on your precious advises.

BR.

Comment: A wild guess... Maybe something related to class loader?

Comment: Yes it might be but I found not way to figure out the problem source. Do I have to load classes computed in node1 from node2? or something similar?!

Comment: Maybe. Which classloader are you using? Are you using the `new GroovyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), config);` from the linked question?

Comment: Yes I'm using the `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader` mentionned in the linked post.

Comment: I've never played with classloaders, but maybe due to the class being in a different classloader, it isn't being replicated. What about using the same classloader as jboss, instead of a `new GroovyClassLoader`?

Comment: If I use the main application server classloader, how am I going to replace the `GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(new GroovyCodeSource(), false);` then? I thought I could only be done in this way?